# Understanding Scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, lexical-scope

I thought I understood scope however, while thinking of a particular code problem I had, I am confused by the following:

```
var a = {
  aFunc: function() {
    console.log(x);
  }
};
var b = {
  bFunc: function() {
    var x = c.x;
    console.log(x);
    a.aFunc();
  }
};
var c = {
  x: 'x is in c'
};

b.bFunc();
```

Question: `aFunc` is called inside `bFunc`, why do I get `'x is not defined'` inside `aFunc`? Isn't this a simple closure where `a.aFunc` can access `b.bFunc` scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isnt this a simple closure where a.aFunc can access b.bFunc scope?

No. Closure is a property of the functions which encloses over all the variables in their scope, **during their definition, not during their invocation.**

In your case, when `a.aFunc` is called, it doesn't enclose the variables in `b.bFunc` because, it is just invoked there, not defined there.

---

Let's try to understand this, with this example

```
function Test1(func) {
  var a = 0;
  func();
}

function Test() {
  var a = 5;
  Test1(function() {
    console.log(a);
  });
}

Test();
```

will print `5`, because when `func()` is executed, the actual function object has enclosed over the variables in `Test`, since the closure happens during the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

No, every function has it's own scope. A function call doesn't share it's scope with it. If you want to share variables via scope you have to put them in the shared scope like this:

```js
var x = 'x from shared scope';
var a = {
  aFunc: function() {
    console.log('aFunc: ' + x);
  }
};
var b = {
  bFunc: function() {
    var x = 'x only in scope b';
    console.log('bFunc: '+ x);
    a.aFunc(); 
  }
};

b.bFunc();
```